# How to change indent guide width?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

[image: beforeafter]

I have looked through multiple resources and forums, but I still couldn't find a straightforward solution. I want to make the indent guide thicker, like in the images above. If anyone has experience with customizing the indent guide thickness in VSCode, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Comment: closed with zero explanation (as far as I can see): https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123981. You can try raising it again. If you do, please give me a link to it so I can follow your issue ticket.